# Why does my paragraph get moved by a animated expanding header in CSS?

Tags: html, css

As a homework assignment for school. I have an issue where the paragraph moves with my CSS animation main header title that expands and contracts. What I want is the paragraph to be in a fixed position and stay there and not get moved by the animation of the header. (Look at it in full size)

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: solid black;
  border-top: solid black;
  border-left: solid black;
  border-right: solid black;
  background: #09F;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#09F, #9FF);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#09F, #9FF);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#09F, #9FF);
  background: linear-gradient(#09F, #9FF);
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #0FC;
}

@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 4em;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}

div.header {
  font-family: "Impact";
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px black;
  margin-top: 134px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  animation-name: expand;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

div.center-out {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

div.center-in {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

div.intro {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #0CF;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  right: 44%;
}

.b1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.button1 {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #09F;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="style3.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Supermercado+One" rel="stylesheet">

<head>
  <title>The How to Draw Homepage</title>
</head>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Tips">Tips</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Learn</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<body>
  <div class="center-out">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Learn to Draw!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="intro">
      <span><p>Welcome to the greatest and helpful place to learn techniques to improve your drawing skills!</p></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b1">
    <a href="index.html"><button class="button1"><span>Start Drawing!</span></button></a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you just need fixed height for `.header`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should transition/animate the `transform` property instead of `font-size` for much better performance, and it will keep elements around it from shifting like that, too.

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

div.header {
  font-family: "Impact";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px black;
  margin-top: 134px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  animation-name: expand;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

div.center-out {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

div.intro {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-out">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Learn to Draw!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="intro">
      <span><p>Welcome to the greatest and helpful place to learn techniques to improve your drawing skills!</p></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule:

```
.header {
  height: 160px;
}
```

Right now header grow and shrink with your h1.